# What does the solid black star symbol on this VNC chart mean?

Tags: aeronautical-charts, transport-canada, symbology

On the Canadian VNC there are symbols, the meaning of I can't quite figure out. In the Nanaimo aerodrome there are several "star" symbols. The unfilled one shows the location of the aerodrome beacon. What do the other solid black star symbols mean?

[image: Nanaimo VNC]

The one circled in red reads "S2 Fl R 209". Based on my knowledge of marine lights I thought that it could describe a [red flashing light](https://ticc.tamu.edu/Documents/OtherInfo/VFR_Symbols.pdf). The star symbol, being in an aerodrome could mean "limited hours" but even then, I'm not able to make sense of the rest of the description.

What does the solid black star and "S2 Fl R 209" mean?

EDIT: According to the CFS, the solid star is a hazard beacon light. Not sure how to decode the text.

Comment: Interesting. The coordinates for 209 indicate that it's somewhere in Victoria and 295 is west of Penelakut Island. Geographically close to, but not exactly where the solid star symbols are located.

Comment: CFS says the solid star is a hazard beacon light.

Comment: Some info on the abbreviations: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Light_characteristic

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's how to decode `S2 Fl R 209`:

`S1` - Identifier. Bearing relative to an aerodrome (N, W, NE). If there are multiple with the same bearing, they are numbered

`Fl` - [Light pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Light_characteristic#Light_patterns)

`R` - [Color](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Light_characteristic#Abbreviations)

`209` - Elevation

[Source](https://www.reddit.com/r/flying/comments/73nlq9/hazard_beacons_on_vnc/dnrnz7u/)

Answer (score 0):

The hollow blue stars are for airport beacons.

The solid blue star at an airport indicates part-time operation.

Your question was on the solid black stars, and those are used to denote hazard beacons.

ref: http://www.flysifc.ca/docs/CAPGEN.pdf  page 38